# stripe node arbitrary precision number

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a safe way to charge payments in Stripe on a Node.js platform. I am currently using `BigNumber` https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/, to perform my operations to preserve the exactness of the calculation to determine the subtotal and totals of an online purchase e.g.

```
let x = BigNumber(numberOfItems);
let y = BigNumber(costPerItem);
let z = BigNumber(taxRatePerOrderTotal/100);

let costToCharge = x.times(y).plus(x.times(y).times(z))
```

My concern is that I don't want all that beautiful arbitrary precision decimal arithmetic to go to waste when I do

```
costToCharge.toNumber()
```

which will change it back to an IEEE764 float, and thus chop off some precision. And yet according to the Stripe documentation it takes a `Number` and I don't believe there is a string version of the `amount` property which would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stripe requires integer cents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge-amount), so you're going to need to multiply that by 100 and convert it to an integer anyways.

Comment: yes but "integer" in the Node case is actually a double representing an integer.

Comment: No matter what precision you have under the hood, it's ultimately going to have to be `round to two decimals` and `multiply by 100`, because a Charge can only be integer cents.

Comment: yes you are right, but that is a necessary inaccuracy when dealing with money, which will follow the rounding strategy of a given state, city, governments. however irrespective of that, there are things you can do to make the value that will be rounded to two decimals inaccurate in non trivial ways, such as performing arithmetic operations on high money values as floats.